How to execute the [sp_removedbreplication] using linked server
I tried this way
EXEC [linkedServer].[MASTER].[sys].[sp_removedbreplication] 'databasename'

However I received this message

Msg 18482, Level 14, State 1, Line 76
Could not connect to server 'remoteServer' because 'connectedServer' is not defined as a remote server. Verify that you have specified the correct server name.

Is it not possible to call sp_removedbreplication using a linked server, do I need to add anything in the command EXEC [linkedServer].[MASTER].[sys].[sp_removedbreplication] 'databasename'?
I have created the linked server and this works fine.

Try this one:
exec ('exec sp_removedbreplication ''databasename''') at [linkedServer]

Looks like your problem is not with replication but with linked server. Did you try steps (sp_dropserver/sp_addserver) from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/errors-events/mssqlserver-18482-database-engine-error?view=sql-server-ver16
